# find in ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this.

```
private ArrayList<String> words;
```

It's a dictionary, so the words are already sorted. By old study I know that a binomial search should be really very very quick, I suppose that Java already implements what is necessary.

So, what is the most efficient way of finding if a certain string exists inside a **sorted** ArrayList ?
Or should I use a different type?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Or should I use a different type?

Try using a `HashSet<String>` instead. Its [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method has O(1) lookup assuming that there are not too many hash collisions. From the documentation:

> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.

A binary search on a sorted `ArrayList` is only O(log n). This is still very fast, but it is not as fast as using a `HashSet`.

Comment: @MarkByers "on average" suggests that there must be a case where its faster than O(1). Now I'm dying to see how that would be achieved. O(log N) can be good enough in practice, especially if using a set means data need to be duplicated...

Comment: Thank you.
Is "contains" method slower on ArrayList? That's because I also need to keep the indicization of the strings.

Comment: @Durandal On average means that if there are hash collisions, it will take more than `O(1)`. I'm not sure how any algorithm can be faster than `O(1)`.

Comment: @BeppiMenozzi Yes, it has to iterate through the entire array (`O(n)`) to test for existence (that is, if you don't make any assumptions about sorted-ness of the data).

Comment: @fox... thanks. Anyway as I said elsewhere, I also need indicization: would HashMap<Integer, String> be a good choice, then?

Comment: @BeppiMenozzi: You would want `HashMap<String, Integer>` for retreiving the index from the word, and `ArrayList<String>` for retreiving a word from its index.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I'll give a check to all these solutions.

Comment: @BeppiMenozzi: You can only give a check to one solution, but you can upvote them all.

Comment: @fo_x86 Thats not my understanding of the word 'average'. What you describe I would call 'best case'. An average is calculated as (here) sum of complexity divided by number of cases. To get this to become 1 there must be values smaller than 1, because as you already said there are cases where the value is larger than 1... my comment was strictly aimed at the misplaced use of 'average'.

Comment: I enter the discussion... O(1)... if I remember what I studied 20 years ago :)
O(1) means: get at the first try, cannot go wrong.
This is obviously impossible in real life. And I also think that it is theoretically impossible to retrieve an information in under O(log(n)), making a search. O(1) refers to retrieving data from a indexed list, say: "get the 10th element", so that's immediate, but whenever a search is made ("look if this exists"), it cannot be under O(log(n)) (that means that the number of steps for finding it ranges from 1 to log(n), being 1 also very rare and log(n) very common.

Comment: In a sorted list, for example a dictionary, the binary search performs searches in log(n) steps, in this way:

look in the exact middle. Is the word before or after the one I found?
recurse and perform again the search in the half set where I know it should be my word.

If the word is not there, I will find it in log2(n) steps. If the word is there, I will find it in less or equal log2(n) steps, being of this latest case at least 50% of times.

Answer (score 3):

A binary search will be the fastest in a sorted array. Testing for existence can be done in constant time if you are using a hash set.

Comment: You're welcome. If you must use a binary search, Google's Guava library already has an implementation. See com.google.common.collect.Ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Depends how many times you're going to try and find a specific string.  You might want to try a `HashMap<String, String>` as this will remain fast as the map grows.

Comment: I could use HashMap<Integer, String> ; would that be faster, compared to an ArrayList, when searching?

Comment: It would be faster than an array list, but no faster than a hashset. Depending on your other requirements, HashSet is probably your way to go.  Sorting is when you need to retrieve more than one element, or have the array in a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be doing binary searches I would suggest you reorganize your data into a `Binary Search Tree`

ArrayLists are often used for sequential operations and random access. If you're going to be doing a search and want the fastest lookup its best to organize your data from the get go. This also has the advantage of facilitating faster inserts/removals and all other operations you'd be hoping to accomplish in the fastest possible time.

There are tons of guides on google and elsewhere to get you started.

Comment: Not really, thanks anyway. I just wanted to look for the existance of a particular word into a sorted array of strings. I was talking about binary search because as I remember it was an optimized algorhytm for the search in a sorted array.